# Views programmatically remove node access (tag)

Tags: views, 8, domain-access

I'm trying to remove the node access check from a view programmatically.
But i'm not sure where the access tags are added/executed.

```
function MYMODYLE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
kint($query);
}
```

If i print the $query the tags are empty, and i can't really figure out where or when those access tags are added. And how to manipulate them.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Drupal: 8.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: 
MYMODULE_query_node_access_alter().

$query->condition contains al de realm conditions, these can be adjusted here.